# Pyinstaller throwing AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups' error

Tags: python, linux, pandas, pyinstaller, pdfminer

I am trying to create a simple standalone script with `pyinstaller`. The script only uses `pandas` and `pdfminer` packages. I have also created a fresh environment with only these two packages and their dependencies installed.
I get the below error when running `pyinstaller --onefile ema_pdf_reader.spec` and my `.spec` file looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['ema_pdf_reader.py'],
             pathex=['/home/erik/PycharmProjects/simple_gui'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['pandas','pdfminer'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='ema_pdf_reader',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

ERROR:

```
(clean_env) [erik@liara simple_gui]$ pyinstaller --onefile ema_pdf_reader.spec 
34 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
34 INFO: Python: 3.8.2 (conda)
69 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.10.15-1-MANJARO-x86_64-with-glibc2.10
72 INFO: UPX is not available.
73 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/erik/PycharmProjects/simple_gui',
 '/home/erik/PycharmProjects/simple_gui']
73 INFO: checking Analysis
73 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
73 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
74 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
78 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2247 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
2247 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir '/home/erik/miniconda3/envs/clean_env/lib/python3.8'
4327 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
4424 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
4448 INFO: Analyzing ema_pdf_reader.py
5378 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
6929 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
6929 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir '/home/erik/miniconda3/envs/clean_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/fake-modules'
12802 INFO: Processing module hooks...
12802 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
12803 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.py"...
12803 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytz.py"...
12816 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pandas.py"...
13457 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
13459 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
13672 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
13879 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
13881 INFO: Excluding import '__main__'
13882 INFO:   Removing import of __main__ from module pkg_resources
13883 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
13883 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
13974 INFO: checking Tree
13979 INFO: checking Tree
13983 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
13993 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-cryptography.py"...
14149 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
14570 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
14619 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
14621 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sqlite3.py"...
14665 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
14666 INFO: MKL libraries found when importing numpy. Adding MKL to binaries
14667 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
14790 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/erik/miniconda3/envs/clean_env/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/erik/miniconda3/envs/clean_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/home/erik/miniconda3/envs/clean_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/home/erik/miniconda3/envs/clean_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 734, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/home/erik/miniconda3/envs/clean_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 681, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "ema_pdf_reader.spec", line 6, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['ema_pdf_reader.py'],
  File "/home/erik/miniconda3/envs/clean_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/home/erik/miniconda3/envs/clean_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/home/erik/miniconda3/envs/clean_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 440, in assemble
    ctypes_binaries = scan_code_for_ctypes(co)
  File "/home/erik/miniconda3/envs/clean_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/utils.py", line 143, in scan_code_for_ctypes
    binaries = _resolveCtypesImports(binaries)
  File "/home/erik/miniconda3/envs/clean_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/utils.py", line 317, in _resolveCtypesImports
    load_ldconfig_cache()
  File "/home/erik/miniconda3/envs/clean_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/utils.py", line 400, in load_ldconfig_cache
    path = m.groups()[-1]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Do I need to specify some other settings in my .spec file? So far I just added external packages to hiddenimports, rest of the .spec file was auto generated with  `pyi-makespec --onefile ema_pdf_reader.py`

Script by it self runs fine and creating standalone scripts that only use standard libraries also works with no problem.

**UPDATE 1:**

The error must be due to ctype DLL detection. It happens when importing numpy as well. I have tried with different versions of pyinstaller (3.6 and 4.2) and the error persists. I also tried reinstalling pyinstaller with pip instead of conda and it didn't help.

**UPDATE 2:**
Executing same procedure on a windows machine works as expected

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar error. See my error below.

What worked for me was to upgrade to PyInstaller 4.8.

Older versions of PyInstaller had an issue inside of utils.py. Specifically, if path was ever None at approximately line 401 in utils.py, the subsequent code failed. This has been corrected in newer versions of PyInstaller.

My Error Message

```
$ pyinstaller perform_optimization.spec

[...]
Cache generated by: ldconfig (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.1) stable release version 2.35
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/strawberry/anaconda3/envs/python-app/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/strawberry/anaconda3/envs/python-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/home/strawberry/anaconda3/envs/python-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/home/strawberry/anaconda3/envs/python-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 734, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/home/strawberry/anaconda3/envs/python-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 681, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "perform_optimization.spec", line 45, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "/home/strawberry/anaconda3/envs/python-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/home/strawberry/anaconda3/envs/python-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/home/strawberry/anaconda3/envs/python-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 440, in assemble
    ctypes_binaries = scan_code_for_ctypes(co)
  File "/home/strawberry/anaconda3/envs/python-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/utils.py", line 143, in scan_code_for_ctypes
    binaries = _resolveCtypesImports(binaries)
  File "/home/strawberry/anaconda3/envs/python-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/utils.py", line 317, in _resolveCtypesImports
    load_ldconfig_cache()
  File "/home/strawberry/anaconda3/envs/python-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/utils.py", line 401, in load_ldconfig_cache
    path = m.groups()[-1]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems here (https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5552) they found something similar. Their setup is quite similar to mine. Still reading...

**EDIT 1:**
I finally made it work. Had to:

1.-edit manually file "utils.py" and add the missing condition

2.-reinstall my version of Python (3.7.4) with shared libraries enabled

Still have to test the final result.